# If value is true show, if value is false show something else

Tags: php

I have some file names stored in my table with a category_id for each image.

I have the gallery all on one page.

So my question is, if my category_id's value is 3 then I want it to show the image.

If the category_id is not 3 I want to display a message saying, "no content", or whatever.

Here is my code. Not sure where I went wrong. Hoping someone can give me a hand.

```
<?php

$newlogos = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT `logo_id`, `creation`, `logo_name`, `category_id`, `org_img`, `new_img` FROM `logos` WHERE category_id = 3 ORDER BY `logo_id` DESC ");

$category_id = ('category_id' == 3);

if($category_id == false){ ?>
<div><h2>No Content</h2></div>
<?php }     

 if($category_id == true){ 

foreach($newlogos->results() as $nl){ ?>
//Do Stuff
```

I've tried a bunch of combinations like this for example:

```
$category_id = ('category_id' == 3);

if($category_id != 3){ ?>
<div><h2>No Content</h2></div>
<?php }     

 else{ 
//Do Stuff
```

Just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Is this CodeIgniter ?

Comment: @AliGajani No it's not CodeIgniter

Comment: `$category_id = ('category_id' == 3);` WTF?!? You're testing whether a string with a value of 'category_id' has a value of 3..... of course it hasn't, in the same way that an apple tree is never a crocodile

Comment: The line `$category_id = ('category_id' == 3);` always evaluates to a boolean `false`, I'm pretty sure that's not what you meant

Comment: String `'category_id'` never equals integer `3`. Maybe in a parallel universe.

Comment: You probably need to read about variables, and how to use them: the result of your query (probably) goes into `$newlogo`. Also, given your WHERE clause, any result you get is guaranteed to have 3 as its category.

Comment: Never paste live-code on Stackoverflow. Instead create a new self-containing example code from scratch with as little code and data as necessary to demonstrate and reproduce what you want to ask about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement here is not correct:

```
<?php
    $category_id = ('category_id' == 3);
?>
```

You are trying to compare a string with an integer and this always returns **false**.

**Edit:**

After you execute your query, you need to fetch the data from the database. After you have stored the data in a variable (e.g. $data), you can compare it like this:

```
<?php
  $category_id = ((int)$data['category_id'] == 3);
?>
```

**Edit: @cwd**:

Here is one way to do it:

```
<?php
  //$con is database connection object
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `logo_id`, `creation`, `logo_name`, `category_id`, `org_img`, `new_img` FROM `logos` WHERE category_id = 3 ORDER BY `logo_id` DESC LIMIT 0,1");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $category_id = (int)$row['category_id'] == 3 ?true:false;
 ?>
```

This might help you.

Comment: Okay obviously I was way off with `$category_id = ('category_id' == 3);` Dang -5 down votes and counting. Could someone correct me on what it should be? If it's not to much trouble.